# How can I check for the TFS 2010 permissions of a project without knowing password using C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, vb.net

I want to check whether the user have access permissions for TFS 2010 Project or not through code. I know only his user name, I don't know his password for TFS  2010. This code should work for any user I requested. I should return true or false, true means the given user have TFS  2010 access permissions for give project. This following code is working for the users for which I know the password. I need this to work for any user. Please help me

```
 Dim ProjectName As String = "ProjectName"
    Dim icp As ICredentialsProvider = New UICredentialsProvider
    Dim ncred As NetworkCredential = New NetworkCredential("Username", "password", "domain")
    TFS = New TeamFoundationServer(Server, ncred, icp)
    store = CType(TFS.GetService(GetType(WorkItemStore)), WorkItemStore)
    Dim Project As Project
    If store.Projects.Count >= 0 Then

        For Each Project In store.Projects
            If Project.Name = ProjectName Then
                If Project.HasWorkItemWriteRights = True Or Project.HasWorkItemReadRights = True Then
                    Console.WriteLine("User have permissions")
                End If
            End If

        Next

    End If
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the list of the users:

```
TfsConfigurationServer tcs = new TfsConfigurationServer(new Uri("http://tfsurl:8080/tfs"));

IIdentityManagementService ims = tcs.GetService<IIdentityManagementService>();

TeamFoundationIdentity tfi = ims.ReadIdentity(IdentitySearchFactor.AccountName, "[TEAM FOUNDATION]\\Team Foundation Valid Users", MembershipQuery.Expanded,ReadIdentityOptions.None);

TeamFoundationIdentity[] ids = ims.ReadIdentities(tfi.Members, MembershipQuery.None, ReadIdentityOptions.None);

List<string> allUsers = new List<string>;

foreach (TeamFoundationIdentity id in ids)
{ 
  if (id.Descriptor.IdentityType == "System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity")
  {
  allUsers.Add(id.DisplayName)  
  }
}
```

Then iterate the list and check every user if he exist in the list.